# Can a piston-like displacement be miscible?

Tags: thermodynamics, flow, displacement

I have a question regarding miscibility and piston-displacement of fluids. My question is as follows:
I am given that a fluid is displaced miscible. At the same time, I am also given that the displacement is piston-like. How can this be? Doesn't miscibility mean that the two fluids mix, and therefore the displacement should not be miscibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be diffusion at the interface between the two fluids.  So the displacement is piston-like, but there is a region of transient concentration variations in the vicinity of the interface.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You wrote that there may be diffusion at the interface, but doesn't miscibility mean that there is no interface between the two fluids?

Comment: By interface, I meant the boundary between the regions of higher and lower concentrations (which starts off sharp).  I used the term "interface" loosely.  In miscible displacement, there are not two separate phases.  I assume you are referring to a groundwater application.  In groundwater situations, there is also hydrodynamic dispersion at the "interface" between the two regions.